# iphone store kit : how to catch cancel event

Tags: iphone, storekit

Here's my problem :

When using storekit for in-app purchase, i'm displaying a "loading" view to tell the user to wait for a few seconds while the process is in progress; but let's say this same user, when the storekit ask him for his itunes account password, press the "cancel" button... How can i "catch" this event in order to hide the loading view?

I'm afraid it could be a cause of rejection for Apple since user's communication is pretty important.

Thanks for any tips!

Edit : I'm not in a transaction here; my first step is to restore completed transactions so the password prompt is trigger by this method :

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something similar was reported in the Apple dev forums.

[What happens when user hits Cancel after asking to restore......](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/32473)

In their case, a copy-and-paste of a method from the documentation created a bug that apparently compiled without error.

```
// wrong, but compiles
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queuerestoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
```

instead of

```
// correct
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
```

If your observer method looks like the first one above, then you're probably not receiving the failure message for the restore operation.

#### Update:

In SDK documentation for `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`, I see the restore failure method for OS 3.1 (2009-11-17) but 3.0 documentation (2009-05-01) doesn't seem to have it.  Strange since the 3.1 doc states this observer method is "Available in iPhone OS 3.0 and later".

To be sure.  I checked my copy of iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/StoreKit.framework/Headers/SKPaymentQueue.h to make sure the restore failure observer method is there.  (It is.)

Comment: you usually see a call to restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError when the user hits cancel. and sometimes it even is a SKErrorPaymentCanceled error code which makes hiding the error message easier.  There are many cases when the user can hit cancel that will result in other error codes.  Enjoy.

Comment: This was the issue :) Thanks guys.

Comment: If anyone wants to know how to tell the difference between a Cancel and a Connection problem from inside paymentQueue:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:, then you should look at error.code. I've noticed that I get error code 2 when I cancel the restore, and error code -1009 when there is a connection problem during a restore. Both errors contain the same localized description: "Cannot connect to iTunes Store". I'm not sure of other error codes. What I do is end the request silently if it is code 2 and show a generic error message otherwise.

Comment: I have to add that it is unwise to check for the value 2, and it would be much safer to check for the error codes provided in http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKitTypes/Reference/reference.html For cancels, you will need to compare the error code to SKErrorPaymentCancelled.

Comment: My two cents: error code 2 (or SKErrorPaymentCancelled if you prefer) is returned for a lot of things, only some of which are a user's intended cancel of a restore.

Comment: In addition, I have once received an error code 1005. That's nowhere in the docs, like your -1009. No idea what caused it and what it means, it came from an iPhone3,3 with iOS 7.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

If the user clicks the cancel button then request will fail -  use a store observer like so...

```
MyStoreObserver *observer = [[MyStoreObserver alloc] init];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:observer];
```

And handle like this....

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My resquest doesn't fail because the first step in my process is to restore completed transactions using the [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions] method. 

But clicking "Cancel" during this process doesn't trigger any particular event (or non i can figure yet)